# The event listener works only once

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

```
todoBtn.addEventListener('click', addTodo);

function addTodo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    todoList.innerHTML = `
    <div class="todo">
        <li class="todo-item">hey</li>
        <button class="complete-btn"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
        <button class="trash-btn"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
    </div>`;
    todoContainer.appendChild(todoList);
}
```

Comment: Is the button (`todoBtn`) this event listener is attached to inside `todoList`?

Comment: What is `todoBtn`?  What is `todoList`?  What is `todoContainer`?  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  For tips and information on how to ask a question, please see [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 2):

`todoList` doesn't exist because you've not created it. Instead assign the template string to a variable, and use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to add it to the container.

```js
const todoBtn = document.querySelector('button');
const todoContainer = document.querySelector('div');
todoBtn.addEventListener('click', addTodo);

function addTodo(e) {
  const html = `
    <div class="todo">
        <li class="todo-item">hey</li>
        <button class="complete-btn"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
        <button class="trash-btn"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
    </div>`;
  todoContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<div />
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is executed every time, the problem is that you are removing and adding the same element to the container, you should instead create a new element every time.

```js
var todoBtn = document.querySelector("#todo");
var todoContainer = document.querySelector("#container");

todoBtn.addEventListener('click', addTodo);

function addTodo(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // new element instead of just removing and adding the same one over and over
  var todoList = document.createElement("div");
  todoList.innerHTML = `
    <div class="todo">
        <li class="todo-item">hey</li>
        <button class="complete-btn"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
        <button class="trash-btn"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
    </div>`;
  todoContainer.appendChild(todoList);
}
```

```html
<button id="todo">TODO</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not working once, rather console the event and check the elements are right.

Comment: How would you know it's not working once? It's very very probable, that the event fires only once.